# How to summarize_each with mixed column class

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the situation, where I want to `summarize_each` a data.frame with mixed column type.

```
> (temp=data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2),gender=c("M","M","F","F"),val1=rnorm(4),val2=rnorm(4)))
  ID gender       val1       val2
1  1      M -1.7944804  0.5232313
2  1      M  0.3938437 -0.8424086
3  2      F -0.3190777  0.3220580
4  2      F  1.3667340 -0.6031376

> temp%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarize_each(funs(mean))
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

     ID gender       val1       val2
  (dbl)  (lgl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1     1     NA -0.7003184 -0.1595886
2     2     NA  0.5238282 -0.1405398
```

This doesn't work because `mean(gender)` doesn't make sense.

**Question:**
If all my non-numeric columns are characteristic of `ID`, thus are identical within each `ID`, can I somehow get `summarize_each` to return that 'unique' value?

```
> temp%>%group_by(ID,gender)%>%summarize_each(funs(mean))
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: ID [?]

     ID gender       val1       val2
  (dbl) (fctr)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1     1      M -0.7003184 -0.1595886
2     2      F  0.5238282 -0.1405398
```

is the output that I want, but I somehow feel like this is doing unnecessary nested `group_by` because there really is nothing to group within `ID`.

Comment: `temp%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarize_each(funs(mean), val1:val2)` or other option is `temp%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)`

Comment: @akrun I updated the question to make it clearer. I do want the gender column to be returned with the unique value.

Comment: You can pass multiple functionis in `summarise_each` , but then it will do that for all the columns.  Do you really need a dplyr or is it okay to have other solutions.  I think with `dplyr`, it may not be possible with `summarise_each`

Comment: Just group by everything you don't want to summarize: `temp %>% group_by(ID, gender) %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Comment: @alistaire THe OP already mentioned that in his post

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `gather/spread` from `tidyr`.  Reshape to 'long' format with `gather`, grouped by 'ID', 'var', get the `first` element of 'gender' and `mean` of 'val', `spread` it back to 'wide' format.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(temp, var, val, val1:val2) %>%
      group_by(ID, var) %>%
      summarise(gender = first(gender), val = mean(val)) %>%
      spread(var, val)
```

---

Or another is using `mutate_if` and `unique`.  After grouping by 'ID', we get the `mean` of the `numeric` columns with `mutate_if`.  As the other columns (i.e. 'gender' also remains in the output) we can just do `unique` to get the `unique` rows from the output.

```
temp %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
    unique()
#    ID gender       val1       val2
#  <int>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1      M -0.7003184 -0.1595886
#2     2      F  0.5238281 -0.1405398
```